# Why is it a must to use defer at the script tag when placing it in the head section

Tags: html

I was trying to include my script tag at the head section instead of body but I realize that in some tutorials script tag are place in the head by using the word defer in the script tag.
I don't really know why

Comment: There's no requirement to in general. There are several reasons why you might want to. We can only guess at the reasons for your particular case.

Comment: If you look at what the [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attribute does, it may answer your question; but as Quentin says: it's entirely optional (though often advisable).

Answer (score 0):

In the usual way (without `refer`), if you put `script` on the `head` tag, Javascript loading will block HTML parsing which is really bad. You can imagine that users will see a blank page for a while due to Javascript loading, and when Javascript's loaded completely, then HTML parsing will be unblocked (users will be able to see the HTML content)

You can check [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-defer) out
[image]

In most cases, Javascript is to handle interactions that only occur after HTML loaded (except you want Javascript loaded and executed before HTML parsing in some special cases). Therefore, to unblock HTML parsing (prioritize HTML content first for users), with the old school technique, we usually put Javascript at the end of HTML to make script fetch and execution after HTML parsing, like below

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div>Your content here</div>
      <script />
   </body>
</html>
```

It will make sure HTML parsing happens before Javascript loading, but the problem with this way is, we need to go all the way down to the bottom to check Javascript in HTML files during implementation, so that's why `refer` was born.

`refer` will help us to be able to use `script` on the top of the HTML file and not block the HTML parsing

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script defer/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>Your content here</div>
   </body>
</html>
```